# how do i convert image into gray scale using python?

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I have 5 images in folder. I want to convert all that images into grey scale.

```
import glob
colorIm = []
for filename in glob.glob('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Asplab/Cifar/*.png'):
  print(filename)
  img = Image.open(filename)
  colorIm.append(img)
  greyIm=colorIm.convert('L')
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'convert'

Comment: You want `img.convert('L')` and not `colorIm.convert('L')`.

Comment: Probably in the last line you should replace `colorIm` by `img`, but neither your identifiers nor the lack of comments help, You may want to re-read the minimum example explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert each image in the list:

```py
import glob

colorIm = []
for filename in glob.glob('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Asplab/Cifar/*.png'):
  print(filename)
  img = Image.open(filename)
  colorIm.append(img)

greyIm = [img.convert('L') for img in colorIm]
```

Comment: thanks for your ans.
how do i convert that all images into numpy array?

Comment: If you want a list of numpy arrays, you can do `greyIm = [np.array(img) for img in greyIm]`. If you want all of them in a one array of shape (5, height, width), you can then do `greyIm = np.stack(greyIm)`.